# Java Collection for hierarchy display?

Tags: java, collections, hierarchy

I am trying to find a way to create an asset management report with this current data structure in the table:

```
Company_Name      Company_id      Managing_Company_id

Target             002             150
Coles              003             150
Wesfarmers         150             100
Shell              001             150
Max Company X      100             null
Woolworths Group   250             100
Caltex             201             250
Woolworths         202             250
Aldi               300             null
PGX                650             600
```

And the report would iterate it into the hierarchy

```
Max Company X
             Wesfarmers
                             Target
                             Coles
                             Shell
             Woolworths Group
                             Caltex
                             Woolworths
Aldi
PGX
```

Is there a Collection which would allow me to manage this structure?

Comment: A tree. So if it's a leaf you can print the report section for that categories.

Comment: Use a custom POJO (entities) where your top level entity will have a list of sub entities and those sub entities will have themself another list of sub sub entities

Comment: The simplest way is to use Map<String,Map<String,List<String>>> collection. It is easy to iterate and to add new members

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the first glance, I was thinking about `topological sort` with a graph/tree to handle your case, but as I was implementing a solution. I think it's not that necessary to solve your problem while just using *double* map to record the relationships:

1. the relationship between `id` and `name`;
2. the relationship between `managing` and `managed`;

And then we can have a solution as:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    List<List<String>> listList = prepareTestData();
    Map<String, String> idNameMap = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, String> managingRelationMap = new HashMap<>();
    List<String> theTop = new ArrayList<>();
    for (List<String> list : listList) {
        idNameMap.put(list.get(1), list.get(0));
        if (list.get(2) == null || list.get(2).equals(list.get(1))) { // no managing or managed by itself;
            theTop.add(list.get(1));
        } else {
            managingRelationMap.put(list.get(1), list.get(2));
        }
    }

    // add specials whose managing does not exist;
    for (String s : managingRelationMap.keySet()) {
        if (!idNameMap.containsKey(managingRelationMap.get(s))) {
            theTop.add(s);
        }
    }

    for (String top : theTop) {
        printManagingStructure(top, managingRelationMap, idNameMap, 1);
    }
}

private static List<List<String>> prepareTestData() {
    List<List<String>> listList = new ArrayList<>();
    listList.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Target", "002", "150")));
    listList.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Coles", "003", "150")));
    listList.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Wesfarmers", "150", "100")));
    listList.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Shell", "001", "150")));
    listList.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Max Company X", "100", null)));
    listList.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Woolworths Group", "250", "100")));
    listList.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Caltex", "201", "250")));
    listList.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Woolworths", "202", "250")));
    listList.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Aldi", "300", null)));
    listList.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("PGX", "650", "600")));
    return listList;
}

private static void printManagingStructure(String managingId, Map<String, String> managingRelationMap,
                                           Map<String, String> idNameMap, int gapCount) {
    System.out.println(String.format("%" + gapCount * 20 + "s%-20s", "", idNameMap.get(managingId)));
    if (!managingRelationMap.containsValue(managingId)) {
        return;
    }
    managingRelationMap.entrySet().stream().filter(entry -> entry.getValue().equals(managingId))
            .forEach(entry -> {
                printManagingStructure(entry.getKey(), managingRelationMap, idNameMap, gapCount + 1);
            });
}
```

And the output will be:

```
                Max Company X       
                                    Wesfarmers          
                                                        Shell               
                                                        Target              
                                                        Coles               
                                    Woolworths Group    
                                                        Caltex              
                                                        Woolworths          
                Aldi                
                PGX
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for this answer. this would work but i found out that there are companies that do not have a manager, like stand alone ones. how do they fit in this solution?

Comment: @gigz Updated the solution, please mark it as the solution if it solves your problem. Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Question about using a proper data structure is subjective. Even with the current data structure, it should not be difficult to obtain the information that you need. You can also go for a `List` of `Tree`. On the other hand, you can easily spin your own data structure eg. Custom `tree` and each root node stored in `HashMap`. That said, Java does not provide a direct way of storing such specialized scenario. If you have a large data set, you should consider using some sort of graph based database.